# Countdown using stopwatch

Tags: c#, countdown, timespan, stopwatch

I am trying to make a countdown using stopwatch, but it seems not to work. Why is that and what can I do?

```
TimeSpan remainingTime = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,60);
...
remainingTime.Subtract(stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

The remaining time always remains unchanged.

I cannot use timer because of other internal code reasons, only stopwatch.

Answer (score 5):

`TimeSpan` is immutable, meaning that none of its operations affect the instance they are applied to. Rather, they return new value:

```
var diff = remainingTime.Subtract(stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

Comment: diff is also a TimeSpan so you can say : 

TimeSpan diff = remainingTime.Subtract(stopwatch.Elapsed);

Comment: And how can I change the value of remaining time or reuse diff so that subtraction performs correctly every time?

Comment: `remainingTime = remainingTime.Subtract(...)`.